# Needs slight change in layout of table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a question on how to display the correct layout in my php code:

OK I want to display all of the questions in a single assessment in a table. Now at the moment it is displayed as below:

```
Question No.  Question                        Answer        Marks Per Answer      Total Marks
1             What is 5+5?                    B             (text input)          3
2             Name three maneuvers you will   ECB           (text input)          7
              undergo in a driving test
```

I want to change the display of the table so that it looks like this below:

```
Question No.  Question                        Answer        Marks Per Answer      Total Marks
1             What is 5+5?                    B             (text input)          3
2             Name three maneuvers you will   E             (text input)                   
              undergo in a driving test       C             (text input)          7
                                              B             (text input)
```

1. As you can see from the new display. I want the each answer that belongs to a question to be displayed in thier own rows, not all answers in one row which is what it is doing at moment.
2. The other issue I have is that it is only displaying one text input for each question. It should instead show a text input for each answer within a question.

My question is that how can point 1 and 2 be achieved so that it can match the new layout?

Below is the code for the current display:

```
$query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
FROM Session s 
INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
WHERE s.SessionName = ?
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
";

// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 


// This will hold the search results
$searchQuestionId = array();
$searchQuestionContent = array();
$searchAnswer = array();
$searchMarks = array();

// Fetch the results into an array

// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
$searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
$searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
$searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
}   

?>      

</head>

<body>


<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

<?php 

echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
</tr>\n";
foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchAnswer[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" "/></td>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

?>

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Where is the code for your table?

Comment: it is bottom of the code, where all the echos are

Comment: oh sorry haven't seen that it scrolls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are E,C and B? Are they the answer for question 2? If so I assumed that $searchAnswer contains them (E,C,B). So I think you should use foreach loop for it.

```
foreach($searchAnswer as $key){
echo "$key<br />";
}
```

or

```
for($i=0;$i<count($searchAnswer);$i++){
echo "$searchAnswer[$i]<br />";
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah ECB are answers for question 2, I will test it and see what happens and get back to you. Do I need to include this after the "Answer" column in the table or do I replace the foreach I already have `foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question)` Thanks

Comment: replace `echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchAnswer[$key]).'</td>'` with `echo '<td class="answertd">'.for($i=0;$i<count($searchAnswer);$i++){
echo "$searchAnswer[$i]<br />";
}.'</td>'`

Comment: Im getting an `syntax error, unexpected T_FOR` in the for loop

Comment: Same except it says unexpected T-FOREACH

Comment: @Wilf, `for` introduces a statement, not an expression, so you can't (afaik) combine it with other text using `.`. Instead use separate `echo` commands, one inside the loop and two outside.